# Akka-Http: How to return a response from an actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am using an actor inside a request with the "ask" pattern:

```
val route =
    pathPrefix("myapp") {
      path("search") {
        get {
          (mainActorRef ? DoSomething("foo")).mapTo[ReturningType].map { result =>
  complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, result ))
         }
        }
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the main actor communicates with other actors and gets an answer back from one of those actors like this:

```
class MainActor extends Actor {

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case d:DoSomething =>
      anotherActor ! DoThis(d)

    // received from anotherActor as reply to DoThis
    case r:DoThisResponse =>
      // how do I send the response back to my “route”?
      pipe (Future{r}) to ???
  }

}
```

How can I send this answer back to Akka-Http as response?

Using "sender()" in the main actor doesn't work as it won't be the right reference. Should I pass in the `DoSomething` some reference to use with "tell" (!) inside the main actor? How do I pass this reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`forward`](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Forward_message) instead of `tell` in the the `MainActor` when sending to `anotherActor`. That way `anotherActor` will not "see" `MainActor` as the sender .

So, basically, you send new messages in the intermediate steps with `forward`, but the actor in the line can simply respond to `sender`, since it does not see the intermediate actors.

Edit: a complete `MainActor`

```
class MainActor extends Actor {

override def receive: Receive = {

   //delegating some more work to another container
   case d:DoSomething =>
     anotherActor forward DoThis(d)

   // sending a response back to "route"
   case r:DoThisResponse =>
     sender ! Response

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. I cannot see how to do it with forward.

Comment: Strange.What happens when using forward?

Comment: Nothing, as in DoSomething the forward trigger something in the other actor which at some point will send a DoThisResponse.

Comment: Ok, I'll write a complete MainActor.

Comment: I did the same thing as you did, it doesn't work. The sender will be the other actor that sends you "DoThisResponse". I even tried removing case DoThisResponse and reply directly in the otheractor with sender forwarded but it didnt work

Comment: thanks it has worked. I have saved the "reference" from the first sender, and used it on the second return.